# Forbidden on sns:ListTopics with wildcard resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-sns

My team has an account with full permission on SNS as long as we act on resources based on a certain prefix

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
          "sns:CreateTopic",
          // ...
          "sns:ListTopics",
          // ...
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:{redacted}:team-prefix-*"
    },
```

We can do most operations just fine, at least the ones we most need, but if we try to list the topics we get a forbidden error

```
SNS: ListTopics, AuthorizationError: User xxx is not authorized to perform: SNS:ListTopics on resource: arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:{redacted}:*
```

We are using the new go SDK v2, and we cannot find a way to query only for our topics, is there a way to list them or do we need list permissions on all the account topics?

Comment: Yes I am not aware of a way to list for specific topics. You can create an issue in the aws sdk v2 repo and see if aws picks it up.

Answer (score 0):

sns:ListTopics does not have a resource filter per (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_ListTopics.html) its an all or nothing operation.
Except from amazon docs: `if you specify a resource type in a statement with an action that does not support that resource type, then the statement doesn't allow access.` [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/reference_policies_actions-resources-contextkeys.html#resources_table)

Typically, this is what the IAM document should look like if you want to be able to list.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
          "sns:CreateTopic"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:{redacted}:team-prefix-*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
          "sns:ListTopics",
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    },
...
```

If separation at the granular level is really that big of a concern, separate AWS accounts should be used.